# MyHouse.wad not working with GZDoom

Tags: technical-issues, mods, doom

Yesterday I found out about a custom Doom map called "My House"

Links: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wAo54DHDY0), [Doom World](https://www.doomworld.com/forum/topic/134292-myhousewad/), [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18Nx7kUQwmxUGoXqL6FiUwFY--up64fgo)

Apparently this needs to be played with GZDoom, but for the life of me, I've no idea how to get this working. For the record, I've tried:

- GZDoom on MacOS
- 64-bit GZDoom on Windows 11
- 32-bit GZDoom on Windows 7
- Zandorum

Of these, none of them even recognise MyHouse.pk3 as a playable file! Even more disappointing, GZDoom and ZDoom won't even play the regular Doom WADs; I've only managed to get Zandorum to play them, but nothing will play MyHouse.pk3.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Its hard to tell if you tried this already, but in a file explorer window, drag the .wad file over the gzdoom.exe and see what happens

Comment: @TimmyJim, I tried that too, but I just get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to the problem.

**1. Location of WAD Files**

As GZDoom suggests, the WAD files need to be available, either in the same directory as GZDoom, or configured as a path under **gzdoom-<username>.ini**. In my case, the WAD files were added to the same directory as **gzdoom.exe**

**2. Running the correct WAD file**

If you happen to have WAD files for Doom, Doom 2, TNT, Plutonia, Heretic, etc. then remove all WAD files, apart from Doom 2, so that in the same directory as GZDoom, you only have **Doom2.wad** and **myhouse.pk3** (You can leave the other *.pk3 files that came with GZDoom). This is because **myhouse.pk3** runs on Doom2. If you try to run it with Doom, Heretic, etc. it won't work.

**3. Running the correct WAD file (alternative)**

As an alternative, you can leave all the WAD files in the GZDoom directory. Instead, multi-select the **Doom2.wad** and **myhouse.pk3** files and drag them over **gzdoom.exe** to run them.